# webstorm file watcher scss, btn the file can't generated when .scss file imported in other files

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, file-watcher

`example：`

> `file a:`
>       `.class{`
>         `..........`
>       `}`
>
> `file b:`
>   `@import "a";`

b.css  can generate but a.scss can't generate a.css

How to simultaneously produce two files?`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have '`Track only root files`' option enabled in your file watcher settings? When it is on, the content of partials is merged into a single .css files when transpiling, so that a single css is generated instead of creating a separate css for each partial. To have separate .css files generated for all your partials, try disabling this option